# Does changing the debug symbol to none improve performance in a VS compiled project?

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, project

Does changing the debug symbol to none improve performance in a VS compiled project?

The default is 'pdb-only' for release mode.

Is there going to be any adverse effect if I change it to none?

Comment: You should probably clarify exactly what language you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, generating a PDB will have no effect whatsoever on the performance of the executable.

Answer (score -1):

yes it does, since the pdb's are not going to be loaded into memory, but for more detail check this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx)

Comment: That is important but is not the same as generating the PDB file.